# Pagination in angular js for html table entries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, pagination

I have some data in HTML table. I have to display table entries using pagination and I don't know how to make it work.some tutorials are confusing since i am a beginner to angularjs. can anyone give a solution for this?
index.html
this is my template to display table

```
<div ng-controller="productscontroller">

<div id="rows">
    Display:<input type="number" min=0 max=18 size=1 ng-model="rowstolimit" />
</div>
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr><b>
                <td><b>Product_id</b></td>
                <td><b>Product_name</b></td>
                <td><b>Highest_bid</b></td>
                <td><b>Bid_expiry_date</b></td>
                <td><b>Less_than_one_day</b></td>
                <td><b>Demand_price</b></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="product in details.productData.products | limitTo:rowstolimit">
                <td>{{product.product_id}}</td>
                <td>{{product.product_name}}</td>
                <td>{{product.highest_bid}}</td>
                <td>{{product.bid_expiry_date}}</td>
                <td>{{product.less_than_one_day}}</td>
                <td>{{product.demand_price}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

controller.js
here i get details from API using featuredeals service

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", ['ngRoute']);
app.controller("productscontroller", function($scope, $http, featuredeals, $location, $log) {
$scope.details = {
    productData: []
}
featuredeals.processString()
    .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.details.productData = response.data.data;
        },
        function(reason) {
            console.log(reason);
            $log.info(reason.data);
        });
        });
```

Comment: Smart Table is a nice directive that solves local and remote pagination. http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are a beginner, I don't want you to copy the answer. Just try below steps.

Assuming there is no Ajax request.

1. List item
2. maintain this variable- skipCount, limit, totalCount, pageCount.
3. assume your totalCount is 100 and you want to show 10 data so your pageCount would be totalCount/limit that is 10 in this case.
4. maintain two array one is for all the product data and other one on which you will have ng repeat.
5. when user will change page call function in controller and pass pagenumber.
   in the controller - Assume user have selected page number 6.

   skipCount = pageNumber * limit (here it would be 60 as per eg.)

so now you just have to update your display array woth 60 to 70 data. the moment you will update the array angular will run the detection cycle and that will update the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pagination, one of the ways is to implement it on the server side also and make API calls by passing the page number as param. On the UI just make some buttons to navigate to a particular page and pass the page number for the API call.This is the best way since we are not fetching data in one go. You can use angular libraries like ng-grid, ui-grid etc. to leverage pagination features.